# pandas Series iteritems in pydevd_utils.py FutureWarning

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem, it seems to be with pandas library. I have installed pandas 1.5.0. The problem/error occurs when debug a code with a pandas Series.
Since pandas has deprecated iteritems, a FutureWarning is showed many times and it causes some error during debugging. I tried installing one version of pandas before, but the problem continues.

```
Error:
PyCharm Community Edition 2022.2.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_utils.py:606: FutureWarning: iteritems is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use .items instead.
  for item in s.iteritems():
```

[image: eww, picture of code]

Any knows how to solve this?. I appreciate your support.

Comment: Update your code to use what it says... `for item in s.items():`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I update that code, now (the error was eliminated), when I am debugging, the process finish unexpectedly. The console shows the following message: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005).

Comment: Sounds like you have a new problem on your hands. Get all the details together and make a new question. But, don't post images of your code next time... just paste the code.

Comment: Thanks @BeRT2me, next time I will paste the code instead of images, sorry about that.

Comment: I solved this error as follows

1. The code was updated using s.items() instead of s.iteritems(). I needed to modify folder permissions on Windows to save the python file with this modification.
2. A new environment was created, the python files of the project was copied to this new enviroment, after this, the problem was corrected.

Thanks @BeRT2me for your support.

Comment: You can also have this problem without using ```iteritems``` explicitly when you just want to access your DataFrame values inside the IPython console in Pycharm (tested on Community Edition 2022.2.3, built October 10th). Tested in a separate console environment the Warning is not there. I think it is a bug on JetBrains side.

Comment: This is similar to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74071666/concatenate-lists-in-pandas-warning-with-pycharm The answer there links to a YouTrack issue for this bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-56361/pandas-Series-iteritems-in-pydevdutilspy-FutureWarning

Answer (score 2):

@brance this [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74501292/constant-pandas-warning-in-pycharm-console-futurewarning-iteritems-is-deprecat) states this is a known PyCharm bug.  Jet brains released a minor bug fix for PyCharm version 2022.3.1.  See [this YouTrack thread](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-56361/FutureWarning-pandas.Series.iteritems-in-pydevdutils.py) for details.

Answer (score -5):

use code

```
for item in s.items():
```

or

```
series.iloc - is old
use - series.loc
```