# Concatenate lists in pandas - warning with PyCharm

Tags: python, pandas, warnings

Here is a minimal reproducible example to get the warning I don't understand.

My dataframe (first 5 rows) looks like this (10 columns, each of which is filled with a list of strings):

```py
Index   HLA A1_D    HLA A2_D    HLA B1_D    HLA B2_D    HLA C1_D    HLA C2_D    DRB11_D DRB12_D DQB11_D DQB12_D
1   ['9F_ABC', '44KM_ABC', '62QE_ABC', '65RA_ABC', '65RNA_ABC', '66N_ABC', '66NH_ABC', '66NM_ABC', '71HS_ABC', '76ANT_ABC', '77N_ABC', '77NGT_ABC', '79GT_ABC', '80T_ABC', '80TL_ABC', '90D_ABC', '95I_ABC', '97I_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '109F_ABC', '114R_ABC', '116D_ABC', '138MI_ABC', '144K_ABC', '144KR_ABC', '149AH_ABC', '151H_ABC', '152A_ABC', '152HA_ABC', '156R_ABC', '163R_ABC', '163RG_ABC', '166DG_ABC', '193PI_ABC', '275EL_ABC']  ['9F_ABC', '44RM_ABC', '44RME_ABC', '62QE_ABC', '65RA_ABC', '65RNA_ABC', '66N_ABC', '66NH_ABC', '66NV_ABC', '71HS_ABC', '76ES_ABC', '76ESI_ABC', '77S_ABC', '80I_ABC', '81ALR_ABC', '82LR_ABC', '95I_ABC', '97M_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '114Q_ABC', '116D_ABC', '138MI_ABC', '151ARV_ABC', '152V_ABC', '156L_ABC', '163T_ABC', '184A_ABC', '193AV_ABC', '194V_ABC', '207S_ABC', '245AS_ABC', '253Q_ABC']   ['9Y_ABC', '24S_ABC', '45EE_ABC', '62RN_ABC', '63NI_ABC', '66I_ABC', '66IC_ABC', '69TNT_ABC', '71TN_ABC', '74Y_ABC', '76EN_ABC', '77N_ABC', '80I_ABC', '81ALR_ABC', '82LR_ABC', '95L_ABC', '97R_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '113H_ABC', '113HN_ABC', '116F_ABC', '131S_ABC', '151ARV_ABC', '152V_ABC', '156L_ABC', '158T_ABC', '163T_ABC', '193PI_ABC']    ['9Y_ABC', '12M_ABC', '24T_ABC', '32L_ABC', '41T_ABC', '45KE_ABC', '66I_ABC', '66IS_ABC', '69TNT_ABC', '71TN_ABC', '74Y_ABC', '76EN_ABC', '76ET_ABC', '77N_ABC', '80T_ABC', '80TA_ABC', '80TLR_ABC', '81ALR_ABC', '82LR_ABC', '94I_ABC', '95I_ABC', '97R_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '113YD_ABC', '116D_ABC', '131S_ABC', '151ARV_ABC', '152V_ABC', '156DA_ABC', '162GLS_ABC', '163L_ABC', '163LE_ABC', '163LS/G_ABC', '166ES_ABC', '193PI_ABC', '199V_ABC']   ['1C_ABC', '9Y_ABC', '11AV_ABC', '35Q_ABC', '65QKR_ABC', '66K_ABC', '69RT_ABC', '77N_ABC', '80K_ABC', '95L_ABC', '97R_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '103L_ABC', '113YN_ABC', '116F_ABC', '138K_ABC', '152E_ABC', '152RE_ABC', '156R_ABC', '156RA_ABC', '163T_ABC', '177KT_ABC', '184H_ABC', '193PV_ABC', '194V_ABC', '275G_ABC'] ['1C_ABC', '9Y_ABC', '11AV_ABC', '65QKR_ABC', '66K_ABC', '69RA_ABC', '73AS_ABC', '76VRN_ABC', '76VS_ABC', '77S_ABC', '77SRN_ABC', '80N_ABC', '95L_ABC', '97W_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '103L_ABC', '113YD_ABC', '116S_ABC', '152E_ABC', '152RE_ABC', '156WA_ABC', '163T_ABC', '184H_ABC', '193PV_ABC', '194V_ABC']   ['rq37YV', 'rqp57D', 'rp67LK', 'rq74AV', 'rq75VT', 'rq140TV', '4R_DR', '16H_DR', '25R_DR', '26F_DR', '28D_DR', '31F_DR', '31FY_DR', '32Y_DR', '37Y_DR', '37YV_DR', '38V_DR', '40F_DR', '47Y_DR', '47YR_DR', '57D_DR', '57DA_DR', '58A_DR', '58AY_DR', '60Y_DR', '67LQ_DR', '70Q_DR', '70QA_DR', '70QK_DR', '70QT_DR', '71K_DR', '73A_DR', '74A_DR', '77T_DR', '77TY_DR', '78Y_DR', '85V_DR', '86G_DR', '96Y_DR', '98E_DR', '104A_DR', '104AK_DR', '108P_DR', '112H_DR', '120N_DR', '140TV_DR', '149Q_DR', '181T_DR', '189R_DR'] ['rq37YV', 'rqp57D', 'rp67IE', 'rq74AV', 'rq75VT', 'rq140TV', '4R_DR', '16H_DR', '25R_DR', '26F_DR', '28D_DR', '31F_DR', '31FY_DR', '32Y_DR', '37Y_DR', '37YV_DR', '38V_DR', '40F_DR', '47Y_DR', '47YR_DR', '57D_DR', '57DA_DR', '58A_DR', '58AY_DR', '60Y_DR', '67I_DR', '70D_DR', '70DA_DR', '71E_DR', '73A_DR', '74A_DR', '77T_DR', '77TY_DR', '78Y_DR', '85V_DR', '85VV_DR', '86V_DR', '96Y_DR', '98E_DR', '104A_DR', '104AK_DR', '108P_DR', '112H_DR', '120N_DR', '140TV_DR', '149Q_DR', '181T_DR', '189R_DR'] ['rqp37YA', 'rqp57A', 'rq77TV', 'rq140TV', '3S_DQ', '9Y_DQ', '13GM_DQ', '23R_DQ', '26L_DQ', '37YA_DQ', '45G_DQ', '45GV_DQ', '46VY_DQ', '55PP_DQ', '55PPA_DQ', '56P_DQ', '56PA_DQ', '66ER_DQ', '66EV_DQ', '67VT_DQ', '70RT_DQ', '74EL_DQ', '77T_DQ', '84QL_DQ', '130R_DQ', '135D_DQ', '167R_DQ', '182N_DQ', '185I_DQ']   ['rq26Y', 'rqp37YA', 'rqp57D', 'rq77TV', 'rq140TV', '3S_DQ', '9Y_DQ', '23R_DQ', '37YA_DQ', '45EV_DQ', '46VY_DQ', '55PP_DQ', '55PPD_DQ', '56P_DQ', '56PD_DQ', '66ER_DQ', '66EV_DQ', '67VT_DQ', '70RT_DQ', '74EL_DQ', '77T_DQ', '84QL_DQ', '130R_DQ', '135D_DQ', '167H_DQ', '182N_DQ', '185T_DQ']
2   ['9S_ABC', '44RM_ABC', '44RME_ABC', '62EE_ABC', '65GK_ABC', '66K_ABC', '66KA_ABC', '66KH_ABC', '71HS_ABC', '76EN_ABC', '77N_ABC', '80I_ABC', '81ALR_ABC', '82LR_ABC', '95L_ABC', '97M_ABC', '99F_ABC', '105S_ABC', '109F_ABC', '114H_ABC', '116Y_ABC', '127K_ABC', '138MI_ABC', '144K_ABC', '144KR_ABC', '149AH_ABC', '150AAH_ABC', '150AH_ABC', '151AHV_ABC', '151H_ABC', '152V_ABC', '156QA_ABC', '163T_ABC', '166DG_ABC', '193PI_ABC']   ['9S_ABC', '17S_ABC', '44RM_ABC', '44RME_ABC', '56R_ABC', '62QE_ABC', '65RA_ABC', '65RNA_ABC', '66N_ABC', '66NV_ABC', '71QS_ABC', '76VDT_ABC', '77D_ABC', '79GT_ABC', '80T_ABC', '80TL_ABC', '95I_ABC', '97I_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '105S_ABC', '109F_ABC', '138MI_ABC', '152W_ABC', '156L_ABC', '163T_ABC', '193PI_ABC', '275EL_ABC']    ['9Y_ABC', '24S_ABC', '45EE_ABC', '62RN_ABC', '63NI_ABC', '65QIA_ABC', '66I_ABC', '66IY_ABC', '69AA_ABC', '70IAQ_ABC', '76ES_ABC', '76ESN_ABC', '77S_ABC', '77SRN_ABC', '80N_ABC', '95L_ABC', '97S_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '113H_ABC', '113HD_ABC', '116Y_ABC', '152E_ABC', '152RE_ABC', '156R_ABC', '156RA_ABC', '163E_ABC', '163EW_ABC', '177DK_ABC', '180E_ABC', '193PI_ABC']   ['9Y_ABC', '12M_ABC', '24T_ABC', '41T_ABC', '44RM_ABC', '44RMA_ABC', '66I_ABC', '66IS_ABC', '69TNT_ABC', '71TN_ABC', '74Y_ABC', '76EN_ABC', '76ET_ABC', '77N_ABC', '80T_ABC', '80TA_ABC', '80TLR_ABC', '81ALR_ABC', '82LR_ABC', '95W_ABC', '97T_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '103L_ABC', '113H_ABC', '113HN_ABC', '116L_ABC', '131S_ABC', '144QL_ABC', '151ARV_ABC', '152V_ABC', '156L_ABC', '163E_ABC', '163EW_ABC', '193PI_ABC']  ['1C_ABC', '9D_ABC', '11AV_ABC', '24S_ABC', '65QKR_ABC', '66K_ABC', '69RA_ABC', '73AN_ABC', '77N_ABC', '80K_ABC', '90D_ABC', '95L_ABC', '97W_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '103L_ABC', '113YD_ABC', '116S_ABC', '152E_ABC', '152RE_ABC', '156WA_ABC', '163T_ABC', '184H_ABC', '193PV_ABC', '194V_ABC']   ['1C_ABC', '9D_ABC', '11AV_ABC', '24S_ABC', '65QKR_ABC', '66K_ABC', '69RA_ABC', '73AS_ABC', '76VRN_ABC', '76VS_ABC', '77S_ABC', '77SRN_ABC', '80N_ABC', '90D_ABC', '95L_ABC', '97R_ABC', '99S_ABC', '103L_ABC', '113YD_ABC', '116S_ABC', '147L_ABC', '152A_ABC', '152RA_ABC', '156L_ABC', '163T_ABC', '193PL_ABC', '253Q_ABC', '267QE_ABC'] ['rq37YV', 'rq57S', 'rp67LR', 'rq74AV', 'rq75VT', 'rq140TV', '4R_DR', '16H_DR', '25R_DR', '26F_DR', '28D_DR', '31F_DR', '31FY_DR', '32Y_DR', '37Y_DR', '37YV_DR', '38V_DR', '40F_DR', '47Y_DR', '47YR_DR', '57S_DR', '58A_DR', '58AY_DR', '60Y_DR', '67LQ_DR', '70Q_DR', '70QA_DR', '70QRA_DR', '70QT_DR', '71R_DR', '73A_DR', '74A_DR', '77T_DR', '77TY_DR', '78Y_DR', '85V_DR', '86G_DR', '96Y_DR', '98E_DR', '104A_DR', '104AK_DR', '108P_DR', '112H_DR', '120N_DR', '140TV_DR', '149Q_DR', '181T_DR', '189R_DR']    ['rqp57D', 'rq74AV', 'rq75VT', '4R_DR', '16H_DR', '25R_DR', '26F_DR', '28D_DR', '31F_DR', '31FY_DR', '32Y_DR', '32YN_DR', '33N_DR', '37S_DR', '38V_DR', '40F_DR', '47F_DR', '57D_DR', '57DA_DR', '58A_DR', '58AY_DR', '60Y_DR', '67I_DR', '70Q_DR', '70QA_DR', '70QT_DR', '71A_DR', '73A_DR', '74A_DR', '77T_DR', '77TY_DR', '78Y_DR', '85V_DR', '85VV_DR', '86V_DR', '96Q_DR', '98K_DR', '98KS_DR', '108P_DR', '112H_DR', '120S_DR', '140A_DR', '142M_DR', '149Q_DR', '180V_DR', '180VTP_DR', '181T_DR', '189R_DR']    ['rqp37YA', 'rqp57A', 'rq77TV', 'rq140TV', '3S_DQ', '9Y_DQ', '13GM_DQ', '23R_DQ', '26L_DQ', '37YA_DQ', '45G_DQ', '45GV_DQ', '46VY_DQ', '55PP_DQ', '55PPA_DQ', '56P_DQ', '56PA_DQ', '66ER_DQ', '66EV_DQ', '67VT_DQ', '70RT_DQ', '74EL_DQ', '77T_DQ', '84QL_DQ', '130R_DQ', '135D_DQ', '167R_DQ', '182N_DQ', '185I_DQ']   ['rq26Y', 'rqp57D', 'rq77TV', '3P_DQ', '23R_DQ', '45G_DQ', '45GV_DQ', '46VY_DQ', '52PQ_DQ', '55R_DQ', '55RPD_DQ', '56P_DQ', '56PD_DQ', '66D_DQ', '66DR_DQ', '70RT_DQ', '74EL_DQ', '77T_DQ', '86A_DQ', '87F_DQ', '125G_DQ', '130R_DQ', '135D_DQ', '167H_DQ', '182S_DQ', '185T_DQ']
3   ['9F_ABC', '44RM_ABC', '44RME_ABC', '62QE_ABC', '65RA_ABC', '65RNA_ABC', '66N_ABC', '66NV_ABC', '71QS_ABC', '76VDT_ABC', '77D_ABC', '79GT_ABC', '80T_ABC', '80TL_ABC', '95I_ABC', '97I_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '105S_ABC', '109F_ABC', '114R_ABC', '116D_ABC', '138MI_ABC', '144K_ABC', '144KR_ABC', '149AH_ABC', '150AAH_ABC', '150AH_ABC', '151AHV_ABC', '151H_ABC', '152V_ABC', '156QA_ABC', '161D_ABC', '163T_ABC', '193PI_ABC', '275EL_ABC']  ['9T_ABC', '44RM_ABC', '44RME_ABC', '62RN_ABC', '62RR_ABC', '65RA_ABC', '65RNA_ABC', '66N_ABC', '66NH_ABC', '66NV_ABC', '71HS_ABC', '73ID_ABC', '76VDT_ABC', '77D_ABC', '79GT_ABC', '80T_ABC', '80TL_ABC', '95I_ABC', '97M_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '105S_ABC', '109F_ABC', '114Q_ABC', '116D_ABC', '138MI_ABC', '151ARV_ABC', '152V_ABC', '156L_ABC', '163T_ABC', '170RH_ABC', '186R_ABC', '193AV_ABC', '194V_ABC', '207S_ABC', '245AS_ABC', '253Q_ABC']   ['9Y_ABC', '11AV_ABC', '24S_ABC', '45EE_ABC', '62RN_ABC', '63NI_ABC', '66I_ABC', '66IC_ABC', '69TNT_ABC', '71TTS_ABC', '76ES_ABC', '76ESN_ABC', '77S_ABC', '77SRN_ABC', '80N_ABC', '95L_ABC', '97W_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '113YN_ABC', '116F_ABC', '131S_ABC', '152E_ABC', '152RE_ABC', '156L_ABC', '163T_ABC', '170RH_ABC', '193PI_ABC'] ['9Y_ABC', '12M_ABC', '44RT_ABC', '62RN_ABC', '63NI_ABC', '66I_ABC', '66IF_ABC', '69TNT_ABC', '71TTS_ABC', '74Y_ABC', '76ES_ABC', '76ESN_ABC', '77S_ABC', '77SRN_ABC', '80N_ABC', '94I_ABC', '95I_ABC', '97R_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '103L_ABC', '113H_ABC', '113HD_ABC', '116S_ABC', '131S_ABC', '151ARV_ABC', '152V_ABC', '156L_ABC', '163L_ABC', '163LE_ABC', '163LW_ABC', '193PV_ABC', '194V_ABC'] ['9S_ABC', '14W_ABC', '65QKR_ABC', '66K_ABC', '69RA_ABC', '73AN_ABC', '77N_ABC', '80K_ABC', '90D_ABC', '95L_ABC', '97R_ABC', '99F_ABC', '103L_ABC', '113YN_ABC', '116F_ABC', '152E_ABC', '152RE_ABC', '156R_ABC', '156RA_ABC', '163T_ABC', '184H_ABC', '193PV_ABC', '194V_ABC', '219W_ABC', '275K_ABC'] ['1C_ABC', '9Y_ABC', '11AV_ABC', '35Q_ABC', '65QKR_ABC', '66K_ABC', '69RT_ABC', '73TVS_ABC', '76VRN_ABC', '76VS_ABC', '77S_ABC', '77SRN_ABC', '80N_ABC', '95L_ABC', '97R_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '103L_ABC', '113YN_ABC', '116F_ABC', '138K_ABC', '152E_ABC', '152RE_ABC', '156R_ABC', '156RA_ABC', '163T_ABC', '177KT_ABC', '184H_ABC', '193PV_ABC', '194V_ABC', '275G_ABC']  ['rqp57D', 'rp67LR', 'rq74AV', 'rq75VT', '4R_DR', '13FE_DR', '16H_DR', '25R_DR', '26L_DR', '30C_DR', '31I_DR', '32Y_DR', '32YN_DR', '33N_DR', '37S_DR', '38V_DR', '40F_DR', '47Y_DR', '47YR_DR', '57D_DR', '57DA_DR', '58A_DR', '58AY_DR', '60Y_DR', '67LQ_DR', '70Q_DR', '70QA_DR', '70QRA_DR', '70QT_DR', '71R_DR', '73A_DR', '74A_DR', '77T_DR', '77TY_DR', '78Y_DR', '85A_DR', '86V_DR', '96EV_DR', '98K_DR', '98KS_DR', '108P_DR', '112H_DR', '120S_DR', '140A_DR', '140AV_DR', '149Q_DR', '180V_DR', '180VTP_DR', '181T_DR', '189R_DR']   ['rq37YV', 'rqp57D', 'rp58E', 'rp58EE', 'rq74AV', 'rq75VT', 'rq140TV', '4R_DR', '11STS_DR', '13SE_DR', '16H_DR', '25R_DR', '26F_DR', '28D_DR', '31F_DR', '31FY_DR', '32Y_DR', '32YN_DR', '33N_DR', '37Y_DR', '37YV_DR', '38V_DR', '40F_DR', '47F_DR', '57D_DR', '57DE_DR', '60Y_DR', '67F_DR', '70D_DR', '70DA_DR', '70DR_DR', '70DRA_DR', '71R_DR', '73A_DR', '74A_DR', '77T_DR', '77TY_DR', '78Y_DR', '85V_DR', '86G_DR', '96H_DR', '96HK_DR', '98K_DR', '98KS_DR', '108P_DR', '112H_DR', '120S_DR', '140TV_DR', '149H_DR', '180V_DR', '180VTP_DR', '181T_DR', '189R_DR'] ['rqp37YA', 'rqp57A', 'rq77TV', 'rq140TV', '3S_DQ', '9Y_DQ', '13GM_DQ', '23R_DQ', '26L_DQ', '37YA_DQ', '45G_DQ', '45GV_DQ', '46VY_DQ', '55PP_DQ', '55PPA_DQ', '56P_DQ', '56PA_DQ', '66ER_DQ', '66EV_DQ', '67VT_DQ', '70RT_DQ', '74EL_DQ', '77T_DQ', '84QL_DQ', '130R_DQ', '135D_DQ', '167R_DQ', '182N_DQ', '185I_DQ']   ['rq57S', '3S_DQ', '9Y_DQ', '23R_DQ', '30H_DQ', '37YV_DQ', '45G_DQ', '45GV_DQ', '46VY_DQ', '52PQ_DQ', '55R_DQ', '56P_DQ', '56PS_DQ', '66EV_DQ', '67VG_DQ', '74S_DQ', '75V_DQ', '77R_DQ', '86A_DQ', '87Y_DQ', '116I_DQ', '130R_DQ', '135D_DQ', '167R_DQ', '182S_DQ', '185T_DQ']
4   ['9F_ABC', '44RM_ABC', '44RME_ABC', '62QE_ABC', '65RA_ABC', '65RNA_ABC', '66N_ABC', '66NV_ABC', '71QS_ABC', '76VDT_ABC', '77D_ABC', '79GT_ABC', '80T_ABC', '80TL_ABC', '95I_ABC', '97I_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '105S_ABC', '109F_ABC', '114R_ABC', '116D_ABC', '138MI_ABC', '144K_ABC', '144KR_ABC', '149AH_ABC', '150AAH_ABC', '150AH_ABC', '151AHV_ABC', '151H_ABC', '152V_ABC', '156QA_ABC', '161D_ABC', '163T_ABC', '193PI_ABC', '275EL_ABC']  ['9T_ABC', '44RM_ABC', '44RME_ABC', '62RN_ABC', '62RR_ABC', '65RA_ABC', '65RNA_ABC', '66N_ABC', '66NH_ABC', '66NV_ABC', '71HS_ABC', '73ID_ABC', '76VDT_ABC', '77D_ABC', '79GT_ABC', '80T_ABC', '80TL_ABC', '95I_ABC', '97M_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '105S_ABC', '109F_ABC', '114Q_ABC', '116D_ABC', '138MI_ABC', '151ARV_ABC', '152V_ABC', '156L_ABC', '163T_ABC', '170RH_ABC', '186R_ABC', '193AV_ABC', '194V_ABC', '207S_ABC', '245AS_ABC', '253Q_ABC']   ['9Y_ABC', '11AV_ABC', '24S_ABC', '45EE_ABC', '62RN_ABC', '63NI_ABC', '66I_ABC', '66IC_ABC', '69TNT_ABC', '71TTS_ABC', '76ES_ABC', '76ESN_ABC', '77S_ABC', '77SRN_ABC', '80N_ABC', '95L_ABC', '97W_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '113YN_ABC', '116F_ABC', '131S_ABC', '152E_ABC', '152RE_ABC', '156L_ABC', '163T_ABC', '170RH_ABC', '193PI_ABC'] ['9Y_ABC', '12M_ABC', '44RT_ABC', '62RN_ABC', '63NI_ABC', '66I_ABC', '66IF_ABC', '69TNT_ABC', '71TTS_ABC', '74Y_ABC', '76ES_ABC', '76ESN_ABC', '77S_ABC', '77SRN_ABC', '80N_ABC', '94I_ABC', '95I_ABC', '97R_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '103L_ABC', '113H_ABC', '113HD_ABC', '116S_ABC', '131S_ABC', '151ARV_ABC', '152V_ABC', '156L_ABC', '163L_ABC', '163LE_ABC', '163LW_ABC', '193PV_ABC', '194V_ABC'] ['9S_ABC', '14W_ABC', '65QKR_ABC', '66K_ABC', '69RA_ABC', '73AN_ABC', '77N_ABC', '80K_ABC', '90D_ABC', '95L_ABC', '97R_ABC', '99F_ABC', '103L_ABC', '113YN_ABC', '116F_ABC', '152E_ABC', '152RE_ABC', '156R_ABC', '156RA_ABC', '163T_ABC', '184H_ABC', '193PV_ABC', '194V_ABC', '219W_ABC', '275K_ABC'] ['1C_ABC', '9Y_ABC', '11AV_ABC', '35Q_ABC', '65QKR_ABC', '66K_ABC', '69RT_ABC', '73TVS_ABC', '76VRN_ABC', '76VS_ABC', '77S_ABC', '77SRN_ABC', '80N_ABC', '95L_ABC', '97R_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '103L_ABC', '113YN_ABC', '116F_ABC', '138K_ABC', '152E_ABC', '152RE_ABC', '156R_ABC', '156RA_ABC', '163T_ABC', '177KT_ABC', '184H_ABC', '193PV_ABC', '194V_ABC', '275G_ABC']  ['rqp57D', 'rp67LR', 'rq74AV', 'rq75VT', '4R_DR', '13FE_DR', '16H_DR', '25R_DR', '26L_DR', '30C_DR', '31I_DR', '32Y_DR', '32YN_DR', '33N_DR', '37S_DR', '38V_DR', '40F_DR', '47Y_DR', '47YR_DR', '57D_DR', '57DA_DR', '58A_DR', '58AY_DR', '60Y_DR', '67LQ_DR', '70Q_DR', '70QA_DR', '70QRA_DR', '70QT_DR', '71R_DR', '73A_DR', '74A_DR', '77T_DR', '77TY_DR', '78Y_DR', '85A_DR', '86V_DR', '96EV_DR', '98K_DR', '98KS_DR', '108P_DR', '112H_DR', '120S_DR', '140A_DR', '140AV_DR', '149Q_DR', '180V_DR', '180VTP_DR', '181T_DR', '189R_DR']   ['rq37YV', 'rqp57D', 'rp58E', 'rp58EE', 'rq74AV', 'rq75VT', 'rq140TV', '4R_DR', '11STS_DR', '13SE_DR', '16H_DR', '25R_DR', '26F_DR', '28D_DR', '31F_DR', '31FY_DR', '32Y_DR', '32YN_DR', '33N_DR', '37Y_DR', '37YV_DR', '38V_DR', '40F_DR', '47F_DR', '57D_DR', '57DE_DR', '60Y_DR', '67F_DR', '70D_DR', '70DA_DR', '70DR_DR', '70DRA_DR', '71R_DR', '73A_DR', '74A_DR', '77T_DR', '77TY_DR', '78Y_DR', '85V_DR', '86G_DR', '96H_DR', '96HK_DR', '98K_DR', '98KS_DR', '108P_DR', '112H_DR', '120S_DR', '140TV_DR', '149H_DR', '180V_DR', '180VTP_DR', '181T_DR', '189R_DR'] ['rq26Y', 'rqp37YA', 'rqp57D', 'rq77TV', 'rq140TV', '3S_DQ', '9Y_DQ', '23R_DQ', '37YA_DQ', '45EV_DQ', '46VY_DQ', '55PP_DQ', '55PPD_DQ', '56P_DQ', '56PD_DQ', '66ER_DQ', '66EV_DQ', '67VT_DQ', '70RT_DQ', '74EL_DQ', '77T_DQ', '84QL_DQ', '130R_DQ', '135D_DQ', '167H_DQ', '182N_DQ', '185T_DQ'] ['rq37YV', 'rq57V', 'qp77RV', '3S_DQ', '9Y_DQ', '23R_DQ', '30H_DQ', '37YV_DQ', '45G_DQ', '45GV_DQ', '46VY_DQ', '52PQ_DQ', '55R_DQ', '56P_DQ', '57V_DQ', '66EV_DQ', '67VG_DQ', '74S_DQ', '75V_DQ', '77R_DQ', '86A_DQ', '87Y_DQ', '116I_DQ', '125SQ_DQ', '130R_DQ', '135D_DQ', '167R_DQ', '182S_DQ', '185T_DQ']
5   ['9F_ABC', '44RM_ABC', '44RME_ABC', '62QE_ABC', '65RA_ABC', '65RNA_ABC', '66N_ABC', '66NV_ABC', '71QS_ABC', '76VDT_ABC', '77D_ABC', '79GT_ABC', '80T_ABC', '80TL_ABC', '95I_ABC', '97I_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '105S_ABC', '109F_ABC', '114R_ABC', '116D_ABC', '138MI_ABC', '144K_ABC', '144KR_ABC', '149AH_ABC', '150AAH_ABC', '150AH_ABC', '151AHV_ABC', '151H_ABC', '152V_ABC', '156QA_ABC', '161D_ABC', '163T_ABC', '193PI_ABC', '275EL_ABC']  ['9T_ABC', '44RM_ABC', '44RME_ABC', '62RN_ABC', '62RR_ABC', '65RA_ABC', '65RNA_ABC', '66N_ABC', '66NH_ABC', '66NV_ABC', '71HS_ABC', '73ID_ABC', '76VDT_ABC', '77D_ABC', '79GT_ABC', '80T_ABC', '80TL_ABC', '95I_ABC', '97M_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '105S_ABC', '109F_ABC', '114Q_ABC', '116D_ABC', '138MI_ABC', '151ARV_ABC', '152V_ABC', '156L_ABC', '163T_ABC', '170RH_ABC', '186R_ABC', '193AV_ABC', '194V_ABC', '207S_ABC', '245AS_ABC', '253Q_ABC']   ['9Y_ABC', '11AV_ABC', '24S_ABC', '45EE_ABC', '62RN_ABC', '63NI_ABC', '66I_ABC', '66IC_ABC', '69TNT_ABC', '71TTS_ABC', '76ES_ABC', '76ESN_ABC', '77S_ABC', '77SRN_ABC', '80N_ABC', '95L_ABC', '97W_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '113YN_ABC', '116F_ABC', '131S_ABC', '152E_ABC', '152RE_ABC', '156L_ABC', '163T_ABC', '170RH_ABC', '193PI_ABC'] ['9Y_ABC', '12M_ABC', '44RT_ABC', '62RN_ABC', '63NI_ABC', '66I_ABC', '66IF_ABC', '69TNT_ABC', '71TTS_ABC', '74Y_ABC', '76ES_ABC', '76ESN_ABC', '77S_ABC', '77SRN_ABC', '80N_ABC', '94I_ABC', '95I_ABC', '97R_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '103L_ABC', '113H_ABC', '113HD_ABC', '116S_ABC', '131S_ABC', '151ARV_ABC', '152V_ABC', '156L_ABC', '163L_ABC', '163LE_ABC', '163LW_ABC', '193PV_ABC', '194V_ABC'] ['9S_ABC', '14W_ABC', '65QKR_ABC', '66K_ABC', '69RA_ABC', '73AN_ABC', '77N_ABC', '80K_ABC', '90D_ABC', '95L_ABC', '97R_ABC', '99F_ABC', '103L_ABC', '113YN_ABC', '116F_ABC', '152E_ABC', '152RE_ABC', '156R_ABC', '156RA_ABC', '163T_ABC', '184H_ABC', '193PV_ABC', '194V_ABC', '219W_ABC', '275K_ABC'] ['1C_ABC', '9Y_ABC', '11AV_ABC', '35Q_ABC', '65QKR_ABC', '66K_ABC', '69RT_ABC', '73TVS_ABC', '76VRN_ABC', '76VS_ABC', '77S_ABC', '77SRN_ABC', '80N_ABC', '95L_ABC', '97R_ABC', '99Y_ABC', '103L_ABC', '113YN_ABC', '116F_ABC', '138K_ABC', '152E_ABC', '152RE_ABC', '156R_ABC', '156RA_ABC', '163T_ABC', '177KT_ABC', '184H_ABC', '193PV_ABC', '194V_ABC', '275G_ABC']  ['rqp57D', 'rp67LR', 'rq74AV', 'rq75VT', '4R_DR', '13FE_DR', '16H_DR', '25R_DR', '26L_DR', '30C_DR', '31I_DR', '32Y_DR', '32YN_DR', '33N_DR', '37S_DR', '38V_DR', '40F_DR', '47Y_DR', '47YR_DR', '57D_DR', '57DA_DR', '58A_DR', '58AY_DR', '60Y_DR', '67LQ_DR', '70Q_DR', '70QA_DR', '70QRA_DR', '70QT_DR', '71R_DR', '73A_DR', '74A_DR', '77T_DR', '77TY_DR', '78Y_DR', '85A_DR', '86V_DR', '96EV_DR', '98K_DR', '98KS_DR', '108P_DR', '112H_DR', '120S_DR', '140A_DR', '140AV_DR', '149Q_DR', '180V_DR', '180VTP_DR', '181T_DR', '189R_DR']   ['rq37YV', 'rqp57D', 'rp58E', 'rp58EE', 'rq74AV', 'rq75VT', 'rq140TV', '4R_DR', '11STS_DR', '13SE_DR', '16H_DR', '25R_DR', '26F_DR', '28D_DR', '31F_DR', '31FY_DR', '32Y_DR', '32YN_DR', '33N_DR', '37Y_DR', '37YV_DR', '38V_DR', '40F_DR', '47F_DR', '57D_DR', '57DE_DR', '60Y_DR', '67F_DR', '70D_DR', '70DA_DR', '70DR_DR', '70DRA_DR', '71R_DR', '73A_DR', '74A_DR', '77T_DR', '77TY_DR', '78Y_DR', '85V_DR', '86G_DR', '96H_DR', '96HK_DR', '98K_DR', '98KS_DR', '108P_DR', '112H_DR', '120S_DR', '140TV_DR', '149H_DR', '180V_DR', '180VTP_DR', '181T_DR', '189R_DR'] ['rq26Y', 'rqp37YA', 'rqp57D', 'rq77TV', 'rq140TV', '3S_DQ', '9Y_DQ', '23R_DQ', '37YA_DQ', '45EV_DQ', '46VY_DQ', '55PP_DQ', '55PPD_DQ', '56P_DQ', '56PD_DQ', '66ER_DQ', '66EV_DQ', '67VT_DQ', '70RT_DQ', '74EL_DQ', '77T_DQ', '84QL_DQ', '130R_DQ', '135D_DQ', '167H_DQ', '182N_DQ', '185T_DQ'] ['rq37YV', 'rq57V', 'qp77RV', '3S_DQ', '9Y_DQ', '23R_DQ', '30H_DQ', '37YV_DQ', '45G_DQ', '45GV_DQ', '46VY_DQ', '52PQ_DQ', '55R_DQ', '56P_DQ', '57V_DQ', '66EV_DQ', '67VG_DQ', '74S_DQ', '75V_DQ', '77R_DQ', '86A_DQ', '87Y_DQ', '116I_DQ', '125SQ_DQ', '130R_DQ', '135D_DQ', '167R_DQ', '182S_DQ', '185T_DQ']
```

To create it, let's run this code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard(index_col="Index")
```

I want to concatenate the lists and get a pandas.Series. Here is how I do it:

```py
print(df.sum(axis=1))
```

I get what I want but I have the following warning:

```py
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_utils.py:605: FutureWarning: The behavior of `series[i:j]` with an integer-dtype index is deprecated. In a future version, this will be treated as *label-based* indexing, consistent with e.g. `series[i]` lookups. To retain the old behavior, use `series.iloc[i:j]`. To get the future behavior, use `series.loc[i:j]`.
  s = s[:max_items]
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_utils.py:606: FutureWarning: iteritems is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use .items instead.
  for item in s.iteritems():
```

I'm using `PyCharm 2022.2.3 (Community Edition)`.
I'm using `Python 3.10.2`.
I'm using the latest version of the library pandas `pandas==1.5.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pydevd_utils included in your PyCharm version aren't compatible with the to-be-changed behavior described in the warning.

You can ignore the warnings for now.

The bug is being tracked [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-56361/pandas-Series-iteritems-in-pydevdutilspy-FutureWarning) on JetBrains' YouTrack system.