# constant pandas warning in pycharm console "FutureWarning: iteritems is deprecated

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

Why does this code give me a warning message?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.array([0,1,2]), 'b': np.array([3,4,5])})
```

It seems anything I do in pandas throws these long error messages, I'm not sure if this is a problem with pycharm or if I'm doing something wrong in pandas.

Comment: Please run `pd.show_versions()` and paste the output in your question.

Comment: @John It's python 3.10.8,  pandas 1.5.1 do you really need to see everything?

Comment: No need to see everything.  The immediate solution is to install a slightly older Pandas, perhaps 1.4 or 1.3.  The answer from brance looks to be your solution eventually.

Answer (score 4):

You can ignore the warning, it is a known bug and is being [fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-56361/pandas-Series-iteritems-in-pydevdutils.py-FutureWarning).